# concate the value into table if record is empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am updating the record to append new content into same row.
Here is the query:

```
    $update1 = "UPDATE review_words SET adjective = CONCAT(adjective, ',', '$adjective'), noun = CONCAT(noun, ',', '$noun') ";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$update1))
    {
    //  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    //  echo "error";
    }
```

This works fine when there is some value in table. But if table record is empty it does not concate the value.

Can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) instead. That's exactly what you're looking for.

```sql
UPDATE review_words
SET adjective = CONCAT_WS(',', adjective, '$adjective'),
    noun = CONCAT_WS(',', noun, '$noun')
```

Note that you're vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please use MySQLi or PDO with parameterized queries to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Amal: I put code snippet, does it still prone to injection?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to substitute the concatenation like this:

```
update1 = "UPDATE review_words SET adjective = CONCAT(IFNULL(adjective, ''), ',', '$adjective'), noun = CONCAT(IFNULL(noun, ''), ',', '$noun') ";
```

Comment: It does not enter anything.

Comment: still it does not insert value

Comment: I just tried it and it worked, can you try the query directly on MySQL and post the result/table data here?

Comment: Thanks dude, but I tried this qquery in phpmyadmin `UPDATE review_words SET adjective = CONCAT(IFNULL(adjective, ''), ',', 'data'), noun = CONCAT(IFNULL(noun, ''), ',', 'data')` but it say 0 record affected. No change

Comment: I can think of 2 cases: 1- your table is empty, 2- all your values in `adjective`, `noun` are null/empty

Comment: KraneBird: did value in the table is empty. And that is the problem I want to solve.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding.. just 1 question, is your table empty?

Comment: Yes, initially table is empty, and I need to truncate it frequently. So next time when I submit query, it does not insert into table

Comment: My friend, UPDATE statement does not insert values, it only updates current values existing in the table.